# Change Column1 to headers

Tags: sql-server

I am currently getting the amount of Males/Females that we have data on in our database. It is displaying as:

```
Gender |  Total
------------------
Male   :  24251561
Female :  24886049
```

I need it to display as

```
Male   | Female
------------------
24251561 : 24886049
```

here is my current code to get the data

```
select a.GENDER,count(1)
from (
    select case when CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(h.ID_Number,7,4)) < 5000 then     'FEMALE' else 'MALE' end as GENDER
from CB_Header h with (nolock)
where h.id_number is not null
and dbo.vf_Valid_id(h.id_number) = 1
)a
group by a.GENDER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #PIVOT

(

GENDER VARCHAR(100), TOTAL INT
)
INSERT INTO #PIVOT VALUES

('MALE',24251561),
('FEMALE',24886049)



SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT GENDER, TOTAL
  FROM #PIVOT
) SRC
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TOTAL)
  FOR GENDER IN ([MALE], [FEMALE])
) PIV;

MALE        FEMALE
24251561    24886049
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Sum(iif(Convert(int, Substring(h.ID_number,7,4)) < 5000, 1, 0)) As Female,
    Sum(iif(Convert(int, Substring(h.ID_number,7,4)) >= 5000, 1, 0)) As Male
  From CB_Header As h
  Where h.ID_number Is Not Null
    And dbo.vf_Valid_id(h.ID_number) = 1;
```

Are you sure you want to use [NOLOCK](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/top-3-mistakes-t-sql-developers-make/) ?

Comment: its a very big table and gets used a lot. don't worry the server can handle it

Comment: without using NOLOCk we run into deadlocks alot